# Creating Average MRR Field

Tags: custom-object, account, roll-up-summary

We use Monthly Recurring Revenue in our Org, with the Billings containing the "Revenue Amount" in a custom Billings object related to the Account.

What I'd like to do is write an Average MRR field containing the average of all Revenue Amounts across all Billings that have a "Billing Date" within the last 12 months. How can I accomplish this?

I have created a formula checkbox field on the Billing to get a "within prior 12 months?" TRUE/FALSE value first, in an effort to have that be a denominator of the total revenue across the same time period.

However, I cannot use relative date values or formula fields in roll up summary filters. I appreciate all the assistance provided.